# Unable to connect to PostGIS databases after Mac OS X Yosemite upgrade

Tags: postgis, postgresql, osx

I upgraded to Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite and am unable to connect to PostGIS databases (PostgreSQL version 9.3 and PostGIS installed from KyngChaos). Typing `psql my_database` returns this message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
       Is the server running locally and accepting
       connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite) suggest some postgres directories get removed during a Yosemite upgrade, but following the recommended solutions doesn't fix my error.

As requested, here are my conf settings (just showing those that aren't commented out):

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 20
shared_buffers = 128MB
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = '../var'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d.log'
log_line_prefix = '%t'
log_timezone = 'US/Pacific'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'US/Pacific'
lc_messages = 'en_US'
lc_monetary = 'en_US'
lc_numeric = 'en_US'
lc_time = 'en_US'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

Comment: Can you show us your postgres conf file?

Comment: Also, check your log or post pertinent parts of it here please.

Comment: @janechii: the recent log says "PDTFATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory"

Comment: @barrycarter: added conf settings to question.

Answer (score 2):

I can't leave a comment due to low reputation, so will extend @pistachionut's answer as a separate one.

In my case the contents of `/usr/local/pgsql/data` are owned by user `_postgres`. Thus, to recreate missing directories it is necessary to run the commands as that user:

```
sudo -u _postgres mkdir -p /usr/local/pgsql/data/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/
sudo -u _postgres touch /usr/local/pgsql/data/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/.keep
```

If this is not done, you will see errors in the log file such as the following:

```
2015-01-05 09:54:21 GMTLOG:  could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": Permission denied
```

After the folders are created, Postgres can be launched with no need to restart your Mac:

```
sudo -u _postgres /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data start
```

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have it working — just needed to modify the directories given in the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite):

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/pgsql/data/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/
sudo touch /usr/local/pgsql/data/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/.keep
```

Then rebooted, and can now connect to my databases.

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much made my answer redundant, but...

When you upgraded PostGIS, did you also upgrade your PostgreSQL
client? Your client is looking for a Unix Domain Socket (UDS) instance
of the PostgreSQL server, but you're actually running a TCP instance.

One possible solution. Comment out these lines in your conf file:

```
# listen_addresses = '*' 
# port = 5432
```

and add this lines:

```
unix_socket_directory='/tmp'
```